# WPF: ListView with templated items scroll behavior trouble

Tags: listview, scroll, wpf-controls

I have the ListView on my app. ItemTemplate is an expander that expands on user click. The trouble is expanding ListViewItem makes scroll jump to a possition, freaking out and behaving very strange. How can i fix the scroll behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: I would wager that your application is trying to get a selected item into view. Look for ScrollIntoView() or EnsureVisible() and see if that is being called. Also, if the expander is using visualized panel, that may cause some odd behavior.

Comment: It's interesting that when i swith to ByItemScroll using ScrollUnit, this problem does not apear. But it's necessary to scroll items by pixel becouse an expander's content can be very hight